# $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{x \tan x^2}{\cos 5x \sin^3 3x}\right) $ Evaluate

Tags: calculus, limits

Find:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{x \tan x^2}{\cos 5x \sin^3 3x}\right) $$

First thing I did was to multiply the function by 3x/3x to get (x/3x)((tan(x^2))/(cos5x)(sin^2 (2x)))(3x/sin3x) where x/3x can be taken out of the limit function as 1/3 and 3x/sin3x can be taken out as 1.

Thus, I get 1/3 lim (tan(x^2))/(cos5x)(sin^2 (2x)).

I am unable to proceed.

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to handle the cosine term. Then express the tangent as a quotient of sine and cosine.

Comment: @Kev: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I started it off for you. Regards

Comment: @GerryMyerson Evaluating limit of tan(x^2) I would get 0/1, essentially zero. Evaluating the cosine gives me 1. That leaves sin^2 3x in the denominator. So the limit DNE?

Comment: That gives you zero top and bottom, so there's still work to be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First express $\tan(x^2)$ in terms of sine and cosine. The cosine stuff is harmless.

The trick that you used once is worth using twice.

Note that $\sin(x^2)=x^2 \dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$, and

$\sin^3(3x)=27x^3\left(\dfrac{\sin(3x)}{3x}\right)^3$.

**Remark:** Before doing the "trick," it is worthwhile to find out what's going on. Informally, near $0$, $\sin x^2$ will be "about" $x^2$, in the sense that the ratio of the two functions is near $1$. Also, $\sin(3x)$ will be about $3x$, while the cosines are very close to $1$. So near $0$, we expect our expression to be very close to $\dfrac{(x)(x^2)}{(3x)^3}$, that is, $\dfrac{1}{3^3}$. The "trick" is introduced in order to make the somewhat vague-sounding "about" precise.

Comment: The limit of cos(5x) is 1, so it can be ignored am I right?

Comment: I am unsure where you are going with the information you provided me.

Comment: yes, since $\cos(5x)\to 1$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Yes, $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(5x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(x^2)=1$.

Comment: Ah, yes, that too, Andre.

Comment: @AndréNicolas an error occur in last line: $3^3=27$

Comment: @pipi: Thank you, I mistyped. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

$${x\tan(x^2)\over\cos(5x)\sin^3(3x)}\sim {x^3\over 1\cdot(3x)^3} = {1\over 27}$$